# Timed Javascript File refresh without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript file which is called in the head tags of my document, and every say 30 seconds, I would want this javascript file to reload.

I have done some research into this, and it seems like there's issues with it pulling a locally stored copy of the file, or cross browser issues...

Pulling it from the cache is not a problem, since the actual file is not changing it just needs to be reloaded.

Would this be an ajax task?
How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question isn't clear enough.

Comment: What more information do you want?

Comment: I am curious, if the content is not changing, then why does the file need to be reloaded?

Comment: It is used to generated ads so there is some computed information in there, and it is much easier to reload it rather than try and break it down to embed the needed parts.

Comment: @MrD. Motivation... why do you need to reload it? can't you use the "old" one?

Comment: I'm trying to make all the ads on the page refresh and they are all served from this one script, so by refreshing this I can ajax the functions to generate the ads and hey presto I will end up with new ads, if I call the ads without reloading the script I will end up with the same ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function foo(){
    $.getScript( url, function(script, textStatus, jqXHR){
        script...
    });
}

setInterval(foo, 30000);
```

> **Caching Responses**
>
> Be default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false. This appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested.

Comment: Sorry, I've just looked at the documentation for it, and it says the params are: url,success(response,status) with the success being optional, does that mean if i just called $.getScript(myscript.js) inside the function and then done the rest as you said it should work?

Answer (score 1):

Make the relevant parts of your JS file into a function, rather than immediately-executed code, and then use `setInterval` in order to call it once every 30 seconds.

```
var myFunction = function()
{
    // do your thang
}

myFunction();

setInterval(myFunction, 30000);
```

Comment: I think you are suggesting to take the parts that will need to be refreshed and embed it in a function? normally that would work but in the case it is easier to reload it all. PLease correct me if I have the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm suggesting.

Comment: I cannot really embed certain parts unfortunantly.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to why you're using the term "embed". Can you explain what *you* mean by embed?

Comment: Sorry I completely misread this, are you meaning I put the above code inside the javascript file?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant to put it in the head of the php file, let me test this now.

Comment: Your solution worked but @gdoron 's was best for my case, but I up-voted you thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get a DOM handle to the `<script>` tag, then set its `src` attribute (Potentially to something like  `blah.js?nocache=somethingrandom`)

Caveat emperor: This will not run what is IN the file in a cross-browser safe way.